# Prove that there is a unique solution to a differential equation in the form of $y = m x + b$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac12x + y - 1$

Find the values of constants m and b, for which y = mx + b is a solution to the differential equation, and **provide a full solution which proves there is a unique solution.**

I know how to find the constants, but how do I prove that

$m = -\dfrac12$ , $b = \dfrac12$

provides a unique solution?

Here is how I found the constants:

Since $y = mx + b$, and $\frac{dy}{dx}$ can be interpreted as the slope $m$, I can rewrite the differential equation as

$m = \dfrac12 x + (mx + b) - 1$

$m = x(m + \dfrac12) + b - 1$

Since the coefficient of x on the left side is equal to 0, I can say that the right side coefficient is also equal to 0

$m + \dfrac12 = 0$,

Eventually giving my constants

$m = -\dfrac12$ , $b = \dfrac12$

But how do I know this is unique?

Comment: Huh?  You know how to find the constants?  If so, then you *have* your solution!

Comment: Right, but how do I prove that the solution is unique? Or am I misinterpreting something here?

Comment: Show your proof that you have the constants... an essential ingredient in a posting such as yours.

Comment: My bad, first post here so I just edited it.

Comment: Your solution isn't unique! First order linear differential equations have an arbitrary constant. What about $y=mx+b+e^x$?

Comment: Should I say this instead $ y = -\dfrac12x + \dfrac12 + ce^x$? How does this change how I would find a unique solution?